# Karma - Unknown provider error: menuFactoryProvider <- menuFactory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

When trying to test my controller, Karma fails with a string of errors all beginning with:

> Karma - Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: menuFactoryProvider
>   <- menuFactory

It seems menuFactory (which is actually a service now) isn't properly injected, but I can't figure out why. Karma output shown here for clarity:

[image]

Here's my menucontroller-test.js:

```
describe('Controller: MenuController', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('confusionApp'));

  var MenuController, scope, $httpBackend;

});

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, _$httpBackend_,  $rootScope, menuFactory) {

          // place here mocked dependencies
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

      $httpBackend.expectGET("http://localhost:3000/dishes").respond([
        {
      "id": 0,
      ...
      },
      {
      "id": 1,
      ...
      }
      ]);

    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MenuController = $controller('MenuController', {
      $scope: scope, menuFactory: menuFactory
    });
            $httpBackend.flush();

  }));

    it('should have showDetails as false', function () {

    expect(scope.showDetails).toBeFalsy();

  });
  ...
  });
```

Excerpt from controllers.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp')

        .controller('MenuController', ['$scope', 'menuFactory', function($scope, menuFactory) {

            $scope.tab = 1;
            $scope.filtText = '';
            $scope.showDetails = false;
            $scope.showMenu = false;
            $scope.message = "Loading ...";

            menuFactory.getDishes().query(
                function(response) {
                    $scope.dishes = response;
                    $scope.showMenu = true;
                },
                function(response) {
                    $scope.message = "Error: "+response.status + " " + response.statusText;
                });
```

Excerpt from services.js (note again menuFactory is actually a service, not a factory)

```
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp')
        .constant("baseURL", "http://localhost:3000/")
        .service('menuFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function($resource, baseURL) {

            var promotions = [
                {
                          _id:0,
                          name:'Weekend Grand Buffet', 
                          image: 'images/buffet.png',
                          label:'New',
                          price:'19.99',
                          description:'Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six main entrees and five choicest desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just $19.99 per person ',
                }

            ];

                this.getDishes = function(){
                                        return $resource(baseURL+"dishes/:id",null,  {'update':{method:'PUT' }});
                                    };

                // implement a function named getPromotion
                // that returns a selected promotion.
                this.getPromotion = function(index) {
                          return promotions[index];
                };


        }])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you had accidentally closed the describe method after injecting module that's why it couldn't inject your service. It works now!

```
describe('Controller: MenuController', function () {

      // load the controller's module
      beforeEach(module('confusionApp'));

      var MenuController, scope, $httpBackend,menuFactory;       

      // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
      beforeEach(inject(function ($injector,$controller, _$httpBackend_,  $rootScope, _menuFactory_) {

              // place here mocked dependencies
          $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_; 
          menuFactory = $injector.get('menuFactory');                 
          $httpBackend.expectGET("http://localhost:3000/dishes").respond([
            {
          "id": 0,
          ...
          },
          {
          "id": 1,
          ...
          }
          ]);

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        MenuController = $controller('MenuController', {
          $scope: scope, menuFactory: menuFactory
        });
                $httpBackend.flush();

      }));

        it('should have showDetails as false', function () {

        expect(scope.showDetails).toBeFalsy();

      });
      ...
      });
 });
```

Comment: Hi Jorawar.  I tried your config and Karma still returns `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: menuFactoryProvider <- menuFactory
`

Comment: are you adding this file to karma-config?

Comment: It's added with `'app/scripts/*.js'` I can try explicitly adding controllers.js to be sure.

Comment: Look into browser that it's loading properly

Comment: Oh, you probably meant the test file.  That's added with `'test/unit/**/*.js'`

Comment: i mean make your you service file is loaded in browser properly.

Comment: in the chrome browser Karma launches?  'Karma v1.1.1 - connected' etc..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118377/discussion-between-jorawar-singh-and-alxs).